# n-canonical embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a stable curve of genus $g>1$ and let $ \omega $ be its dualizing sheaf. Let $n$ be a integer larger than 2. Does anyone knows how to show that $\omega^{\otimes n}$ separates points and tangent vectors? that is, to show $\omega^{\otimes n}$ provives an embedding in a projective space? If $ C $ is a smooth curve, ok, we could use the Riemann-Roch for do it, but and in this nodal case? Does Anyone knows?

Answer (score 6):

You have to suppose $C$ has arithmetic genus $\ge 2$ and is stable (nodal is not enough as $\omega$ might then be trivial on some irreducible components).

A proof can be found in [Deligne-Mumford: The irreducibility of the space of curves of given genus](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_1969__36_/PMIHES_1969__36__75_0/PMIHES_1969__36__75_0.pdf), Theorem 1.2. It is not so easy.